# Adding array to sheet names

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code to retain sheets that I need and delete the rest.

```
Sub DeleteSheets1()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" And xWs.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have around 6 sheets that I want to retain. I need help modifying the syntax to accommodate multiple sheets. Something like below

```
if xWs.Name <> ("sheet1", "sheet2"....) then xws.delete
```

Comment: Change `if xWs.Name <> ("sheet1", "sheet2"....) then xws.delete`  ...   to     
 ...`if Left(xWs.Name,5) <> "sheet") then xws.delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `arr` is an array of the sheets to retain:

```
Sub DeleteSheets1()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, s As String, i As Long
    Dim skp As Boolean
    arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    n = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        s = Sheets(i).Name
        skp = False
        For Each a In arr
            If s = a Then skp = True
        Next a
        If Not skp Then Sheets(i).Delete
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Majid  Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The `valueInArray` boolean function could work the code easier:

```
Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim cnt As Long

    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(myValue) = CStr(myArray(cnt)) Then
            valueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cnt

End Function

Sub DeleteSheets()


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = Worksheets.Count

    Dim arrWks As Variant
    arrWks = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    For cnt = Worksheets.Count To 1
        If Not valueInArray(Worksheets(cnt).Name, arrWks) Then
            Worksheets(cnt).Delete
        End If
    Next cnt

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The `valueInArray` function gets value to search for `myValue` and array where to search for this value `myArray`. It loops through all elements of the array and if it finds the same `String` of the passed value, it returns `True` and exits. If it is not found, it returns `False`, as this is the default.

Comment: too advanced for me, sorry.

Comment: @Majid - simply copy the function to a new module and leave it there. Then call it like `If valueInArray(value, array()) Then`

Comment: Thanks, Vityata. I am still a beginner. Your answer may work but I'll take time to understand. I used Gary's answer. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Majid - you are welcome. In general, working with functions is quite tough at the beginning, but after some time it becomes easier. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim arr         As Variant

arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(ws.Name, arr, 0)) Then ws.Delete
    Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one doesn't quite fulfil the requirement of an array, but it's another way of using a single loop.

It looks for an occurrence of the sheet name in the `RetainSheets` string.  Each sheet name is surrounded by `|` just in case there's a sheet name within a sheet name *eet1Sh* as an example.
The code will not attempt to delete the last worksheet in the workbook either.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim RetainSheets As String

    RetainSheets = "|Sheet1|Sheet2|"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each wrkSht In Worksheets
        If InStr(RetainSheets, wrkSht.Name) = 0 And Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            wrkSht.Delete
        End If
    Next wrkSht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```